# export list of dictionaries to JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have one dictionary that I have managed to export to JSON format

```
{
"Services": [
    {
        "Name": "Service1",
        "Products": {
            "product1": "yes",
            "product2": "yes",
            "product3": "no",
            "product4": "yes",
            "product5": "yes"
        }
    }
]
```

}

The code that I use is the following :

```
end_result["Services"] = lst
    with open("json_test.json","w") as outputfile:
        json.dump(end_result,outputfile,indent = 4)
```

where `end result` is the dictionary that I want to write to the JSON file. This block of code is
part of a really big loop.All the dictionaries are created in this loop.  For the first dictionary, I have managed to export it to JSON. I want for the second and third dictionary to export it to JSON.

The result would be like this:

```
   {
"Services": [
    {
        "Name": "Service1",
        "Products": {
            "product1": "yes",
            "product2": "yes",
            "product3": "no",
            "product4": "yes",
            "product5": "yes"
        }
    }
]
```

}

```
   {
    "Services": [
        {
            "Name": "Service1",
            "Products": {
                "product1": "yes",
                "product2": "yes",
                "product3": "no",
                "product4": "yes",
                "product5": "yes"
            }
        }
    ]
}

   {
    "Services": [
        {
            "Name": "Service1",
            "Products": {
                "product1": "yes",
                "product2": "yes",
                "product3": "no",
                "product4": "yes",
                "product5": "yes"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

All the dictionaries must be on the same JSON file. The list of dictionaries can consist of one dictionary or more. That depends on the findings of the algorith. So far, I have only a dictionary in each list but it can have more dictionaries. For instance, I can have service1 and service2 in a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Your desired output is NOT valid JSON.

Comment: The desired output seems like [JSONL](https://jsonlines.org/). Also, whats the point of multiple lines that appear to have the same data?

Comment: In the services, I can have more than one service. For instance, I have the "Service1" but I can also have "Service2" and "Service3"

Comment: @rv.kvetch, for `ndjson` or `jsonl` each line should be valid JSON, which is not the case here (with the formatting they present).

Comment: Isnt the very first entry of JSON a valid format ?  What can I do differently ?

Comment: the first one is valid, the one where you have 3 JSON objects  (_The result would be like this:_) is not. Probably you want array of JSON objects?

Comment: Yes an array of JSON object would be the best. Each JSON object represents a company and information about it. I have not yet managed to create variables that represent the companies. So one JSON object contains information for one company.

Comment: Why don't you append all your dictionaries in a list and dump this list to a json file at once?